# I need to call api inside a forEach and get those responses into a array and return. But it returns as an empty array in js(javascript)

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, foreach, synchronous

Here is my code and the language is javascript.

```
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let responses=  await axios.get("https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys/"+id+"/responses/bulk", {
        headers: {
          'Authorization':config
        }
      })

      resolve(responses.data)
    });
  }
responses_by_nicknames=async(nicknames)=>{

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
   
    _.forEach(nicknames, function(value) {
      let  responses_by_nicknames2=[]

    let obj ={"nickname":value.nickname}
      console.log(value)
      _.forEach(value.surveys,async function(value2) {

    Promise.all([responses_by_id(value2.id)]).
       then(body => { 
      
                 responses_by_nicknames2.push(res)
        
      })
})
      console.log("!!@@",responses_by_nicknames2)
    })
resolve(responses_by_nicknames)
 })
 }
```

Console.log  gives an empty array also. As I understood the console log and "resolve" execute before API is called.

Comment: `forEach` doesn't support `async` use `forof` or `while` to work with promises

Comment: Ahmed Khan still not working